# What does "the input difference of each Sbox should be zero" mean?

Tags: s-boxes

While going through the article, [The MALICIOUS Framework: Embedding Backdoors into Tweakable Block Ciphers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/986.pdf). I came across this statement

> in order to have a deterministic differential characteristic all Sboxes must be differentially inactive (i.e., the input difference of each Sbox should be zero)

What does the input difference of SBox mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts underlying differential cryptanalysis?

Comment: that is what i am trying to understand

Comment: Whatever the case, would you mind sharing a link to the page where the article can be downloaded (or purchased if behind a paywall)?

Comment: This one --> https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/986